# How do I set custom ticks along the Xaxis in D3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, data-visualization

I had data that have ticks like

```
"ticks":[[[0, 13], "A"], [[13, 15], "B"], [[15, 17], "C"], [[17, 19], "D"]]
```

and i try some simple code

```
var x_data = json["x-axis"];
x.domain([x_data.range[0],x_data.range[1]]);
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal();
var X_ticks = x_data.ticks;
xScale.domain(X_ticks.map(function(d){return d[0];})).range(x);
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
 .scale(xScale)
 .ticks(20)
 .tickSubdivide(true)
 .orient("bottom");
```

but it's not working any idea? or tip? trick? to show label and range for custom type of ticks

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Have you seen [the documentation for `axis.tickValues()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Axes#wiki-tickValues)?

Comment: ya but i and i do the same and it's working here http://jsfiddle.net/NikhilS/3hgra/  but i have this json whichis not in my hand so i need to manage somehow with this data

Comment: How does the JSON specify the ticks?

Comment: don't know some server stuff they send data with their calculation but for now i can't stop work for this issue i am making my own array from json and keep moving forward.. and solve after some free time .

Comment: No, I mean what do the numbers mean?

Comment: it's marks of students and the chart indicates the number of students per mark range like [0,13],[13,21] like that

Comment: So the first value in each pair determines where the tick should go?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39680/discussion-between-amit-rana-and-lars-kotthoff)